# WebClient download file - access is denied

Tags: c#

```
private void sendmsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextBox1.Text))
        Environment.Exit(0);
    openFileDialog1.FileName = this.TextBox1.Text + "\\Unturned_BE.exe";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1134788916642336910/1134789171848953927/Rxl.dll", this.TextBox1.Text + "\\Unturned_Data\\Managed");
            
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

my English is very bad, I ran into a problem that the folder refuses access to install the file

I tried to run the project as an administrator and give more rights, but nothing helped

Comment: Your user does not have rights to write there, so you should write to a folder where your user has rights. Did you try to write into that folder after you gave the rights?

Comment: Note that the second parameter of [DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile) is a file name. You seem to be passing a directory name here.

Comment: Just a comment for other who are reading this posting.  DownloadFile uses FTP according to the documentation.  FTP has two modes 1) Binary 2) Text.  Binary mode downloads file without any changes.  Binary mode replaces character like return characters.  It appears this method uses binary mode.  There is another mode to download text which modifies the text using encoding.  Microsoft should write there method to following the original Unix method that made sense.  Not to invent their own methods that are problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Read the official Microsoft documentation about WebClient.DownloadFile

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-7.0

When calling the WebClient.DownloadFile function, the second argument must be the name of the file or the full path to the file to be written. If the file does not exist, it will be created automatically. If you specify a folder instead of a file, you will get an "Access Denied" error.

Code example:

```
private void sendmsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextBox1.Text))
        Environment.Exit(0);
    openFileDialog1.FileName = this.TextBox1.Text + "\\Unturned_BE.exe";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1134788916642336910/1134789171848953927/Rxl.dll", this.TextBox1.Text + "\\Unturned_Data\\Managed\\Rxl.dll");
            
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```